# Api server in EC2 not able to connect to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, localhost

I am new to aws as well as server and it's configurations.

I have an app server which basically is an API server.

When I test running with my localhost I am able to access it.

`curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:5000/api/Supplier`'

But not with my machine public or private or elastic IPs.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://xxx-xx-xx-xx:5000/api/Supplier'
```

i get the following error

```
(7) Failed to connect to xxx-xx-xx-xx port 5000: Connection refused
```

Are there any additional things that are needed here?

Comment: tried checking SGs and NACL possibly?

Comment: You've indicated two different problems. One is EC2 connecting to RDS and the other is you connecting to the web server on your EC2 instance. Which is it?

Comment: For help diagnosing this, see https://alestic.com/2009/08/ec2-connectivity/. It's most likely that you have not allowed inbound traffic on port 5000 of your instance's security group, or that your web server is only listening on the loopback interface (127.0.0.1).

Comment: @jarmod I have configured my RDS with private IP of app server.
when I run curl on localhost I am able to acres the API . 
when I run on my private IP I am getting  Could not resolve host: xxx-xx-xx-xx

Comment: Which problem are you asking for help with? EC2 to RDS, or your laptop to the API server on port 5000?

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan I have added the security group with inbound traffic as 
All ICMP - IPv4
with source
sg-01f5673956xxxxxxx (app server security group )

Comment: were you able to ping your RDS? if yes probably port issue @sumanthshetty

Comment: @jarmod I am running the localhost on my app server machine . Which provides me the desired output.
but when I use my private IP in place of localhost in this command curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:5000/api/Supplier. 
I get the error " Could not resolve host: xxx-xx-xx-xx –"

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan How can ping my RDS with my ec2 instance?

Comment: *from your EC2 instance, if you have hostname, you can ping

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan ping not working